# R and gWidgets: Event trigger on close of a widget

Tags: r, gwidgets, rgui

I'm currently working on a small GUI based application using gWidgets (RGtk2).
I've encountered a question which I was unable to solve by myself using the documentation provided in the gWidgets package:

Is it possible to trigger an event, i.e. a function, when the user clicks on the red cross to close the GUI / widgets/ main window? For usability reasons I don't want to have an extra button though it will definitely work.

PS: I don't think an example is necessary here but if any of you insists I will add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
addhandlerdestroy( myWidget, handler = f_exit )
```

where

```
f_exit <- function( h,...
{
  # your code, maybe simply
  dispose( myWidget )
}
```